# Cannot disable validation on controler

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

In mvc 4, I have to following snippet:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public async Task<ActionResult> EmailHandle()
{
    OtherClass.SomeProcess(Request.Form);
}

public static class OtherClass 
{
   public static void SomeProcess(NameValueCollection coll) 
   {
       var value = coll["someKey"];
   }
}
```

The problem is that despite `ValidateInput(false)` I still cannot get value from collection. (`var value = coll["someKey"];`) due to error:

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client
```

Why it sill happens? I do not want to disable validation globally.

Comment: What kind of input you have? and what data you pass in?

Comment: Sample data: `<xxxxxx@company.com>`

Comment: Try without the `<` and `>`, does it work?

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin it is working. That is why I want to disable validation. These values are got from external system, so I cannot do much.

Comment: Does disabling the global validation help? (this is only for debugging purposes). Like in this link: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client/

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin found solution. See my answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

Found issue. TO allow reading dangerous values we can use:

```
Request.Unvalidated().Form
```

`Unvalidated()` extension method is available in `System.Web.Helpers`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

```
[AllowHtml]
```

Comment: `[AllowHtml]` can by used only on properties. I do not have any model, fetching data directly from `Form`.

Comment: please have a look and check what you are missing. https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/What-is-ValidateInputfalse-attribute-its-Uses-and-Examples-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx